# getting sidebar column to extend to bottom of page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, position

I am working on getting a two column layout that extends to the bottom of my page.
  However, my sidebar cuts off at the `container-fluid` height even though I am trying to get it to extend to the whole page.

What is weird is that my content column works fine.

**HTML**:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid columns no-margin fill">
        <div id="sidebar" class="span2 columns no-margin right-edge"></div>
        <div id="contentWrapper" class="span10 columns no-margin pull-right"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```css
html, body, form {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-image:url("../../images/lightGreyBackground.png");
    background-repeat: repeat;
    font-family:"Segoe UI", Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
}
.container-fluid {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0px;
}
.columns {
    height: 100%;
    min-height:100%;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
.fill {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
.no-margin {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
}
.right-edge {
    border-right: 1px;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-color: #CCCCCC;
}
#sidebar {
    background-color: White;
    padding-top:15px;
}
```

Comment: [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) it for us please.

Comment: For starters, how are these columns? They're all set to 100% width. You have classes which aren't being used. Can you post more than this?

Comment: I think there's something else in your code causing you problems. I set this up as a fiddle and it worked fine. http://jsfiddle.net/g83Pm/

Comment: @dudledok, this is a Bootstrap page, which is why it's columns and a lot of the classes aren't defined.

Comment: @TimWasson, yeah I realise now. Didn't look properly first time. And indeed, it works fine with what we're given.

Comment: You have to provide enough code to reproduce the problem, otherwise there's nothing to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For have 2 column :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .container-fluid { width: 100%;}
            .float {
                float: left;
                width: 50%; /* Size colonne */
                margin: 1em 0; /* Margin colonne */
            }
            .spacer { clear: both; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="float">Colonne 1</div>
            <div class="float">Colonne 2</div>
            <div class="spacer"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Use the framework [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) or [960.gs](http://960.gs), powerful front-end framework for faster and easier web development.

With bootstrap 3 :

```
<div class="container">
  <!-- Example row of columns -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View details »</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View details »</a></p>
   </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in.</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View details »</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have to say, Bootstrap 3's grid system is _glorious_